# error when linking button to class/page

Tags: android

Hello why wont this work? 
My plan is to have 2 navigate buttons that link to eternal page/classes in my application?
Why does not this work and is this a good way of doing that?
I think of make a if and else statement but i dont now is it is better for this action.
the problem is that it become a error on } tags at the end of the application.
Else the application seems to working good. I have tried to remove } tags and put in more but that does not help.

```
enter code here
package tm.andrioid.com;

 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.app.Dialog;
 import android.app.ListActivity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.Menu;
 import android.view.MenuInflater;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.Button;



import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Button;

 public class indexActivity extends Activity
 {
 public void onCreate(Bundle icicle)
 {
  super.onCreate(icicle);
  setContentView(R.layout.main);


  Button bprodukter = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bprodukter); // to link to page 1
  bprodukter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(View arg0) {

     Intent i = new Intent(indexActivity.this, produkter.class);

     startActivity(i);

     } 

 private void onClickbpositionButton(){
   Button bposition = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bpoistion);  // to link to page 2
      bposition.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View arg0) {

         Intent e = new Intent(indexActivity.this, position.class);

         startActivity(e);

         }
      }
      });
  }
 }
```

Comment: The error is } in the end of the application, but i dont think that is the problem!

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not a sufficient error description to actually help you.

Comment: the i hope i put in a better problem space

Comment: Intent e = new Intent(indexActivity.this, position.class);
           startActivity(e);
       }
   });
      }

Comment: then it is a error on the last }, and if i remove that one i turns out more error

Comment: Also the bproduker is blue on the R.id.bproduker but the R.id.bposion is not, maybe it have something to do with that?

Answer (score 0):

You're not closing your onCreate() method:

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle icicle)
 {
     ....

     bposition.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         ....
         Intent i = new Intent(indexActivity.this, produkter.class);
         startActivity(i);

     } 

// Missing closing }!!!

 private void onClickbpositionButton() {
     ...
 }
```

Comment: sorry but i try to put that in as well but that does not work?
If you should navigate a button to a page is this the why you should done?